# Wrong distance calculation with MongoDB 2.6

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

I have the coordinates field stored like this :

```
     ...
     "coordinates" : {
                                            "lng" : -6.57604948,
                                            "lat" : 34.26329164
                                    },
```

The spherical index :

```
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "coordinates" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "name" : "coordinates_2dsphere",
            "ns" : "hospitals.markers",
            "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 1
    }
```

When i run :

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear: "hospitals",   
           near: [ -6.578296, 34.264061000000005 ],   
           spherical: true                }  )
```

it gives for distance something like 400 (radians ?)
the distance should not be more than 1 km , but I get these huge values 
do you have any suggestions ? 
as for doctrine MongoDB doctrine i used a [branch](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb) 1.2.*  and for odm i used the [last release](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect introduced to MongoDB in the recent release of 2.6.0. Does it work as expected in 2.4.x?

See:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13540

Comment: What I concluded is that in 2.6.0, if using spherical: true  , the distance is calculated in meters ..
So these huge values are meters ..I think